# Running scripts in elasticsearch without enabling dynamic scripting

Tags: elasticsearch

Enabling dynamic scripting has proven costly to our servers. How can I run scripts without enabling dynamic scripting?

Comment: That also depends on how performant those scripts are. You're saying those scripts are 100% tuned but still slow down your server?

Answer (score 0):

You can write the script to disk and then access it with `file` parameter like this

```
"script": {
    "file": "your_custom_script",
    "lang": "groovy",
    "params": {
        "your_param_value": 3
    }
}
```

store the file `your_custom_script.groovy` in your ES `config/scripts` folder.

Refer to [this blog](https://www.elastic.co/blog/running-groovy-scripts-without-dynamic-scripting) for more info. Although I am not sure how much performance benefit you will get.